# Android Spinner not showing extra item's text

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

**EDIT:** Turns out the problem was due to the Material Spinner library. When I use AppCompatSpinner, it works fine.

---

**Context:** I was fiddling with [this Material Spinner library](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner). I extended ArrayAdapter so I could add an extra item to it (which I'd like to eventually convert to an "Add New Item" button in the future).

**Problem:** The adapter inflates the extra TextView properly. It detects the width of the text just fine. The problem is the text itself just doesn't appear.

[image: Blank Item] [image: Blank Dropdown Item]

**Attempt:** I speculated the problem might be due to the text color so I changed the theme to Light (in hopes that the text color would show up as black) but that didn't work. I also tried to setTextColor to Color.WHITE but that didn't work either. I then tried using a color from colors.xml but of course it didn't work. I tried to setAlpha to 1, didn't work.

---

Not exactly sure what the problem is so I'll post my code below.

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class TaskArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

public static final int VIEW_TYPE_ADD_ITEM = -1;
private static final int OFFSET = 1; // # of other view types

private List<Task> mTasks;

public TaskArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Task> tasks) {
    super(context, resource, tasks);
    mTasks = tasks;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    //Workaround waiting for a Google correction (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79011)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return 1;
    }
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    position = position - OFFSET;
    return (position == -1) ? VIEW_TYPE_ADD_ITEM : super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return OFFSET + super.getCount();
}

@Override
public Task getItem(int position) {
    position = position - OFFSET;
    return (position == -1) ? null : super.getItem(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    position = position - OFFSET;
    return (position == -1) ? 0 : super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ADD_ITEM) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        final int resid = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item;
        final TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(resid, parent, false);
        textView.setText("Testing Add New Item Here");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setTag(VIEW_TYPE_ADD_ITEM);
        return textView;
    }
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ADD_ITEM) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        final int resid = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
        final TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(resid, parent, false);
        textView.setText("Testing Add New Item Here");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setTag(VIEW_TYPE_ADD_ITEM);
        return textView;
    }
    return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

}

**Setting Up the Adapter**

```
public void showTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    final TaskArrayAdapter taskAdapter = new TaskArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tasks);
    taskAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mTaskSpinner.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
}
```

**Spinner:**

```
<com.example.test.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/task_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:ms_multiline="false"
        app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="false"
        app:ms_enableErrorLabel="false"
        app:ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
        app:ms_baseColor="@color/transparent_blue"
        app:ms_highlightColor="@color/md_purple_400"
        app:ms_errorColor="@color/error_color"
        app:ms_thickness="2dp"
        app:ms_alignLabels="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your code and it works fine for me, sort of.

getView is for the view displayed before clicking the spinner
getDropdownView is used for the view repeated when the pop-up appears.

so you probably don't want the getItemViewType code within getView()

Can you show your theme/style that might affect the spinner?

Comment: I'm using "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar."

Other than that, I don't think I made much style modification on the Spinner aside from the MaterialSpinner view.

Comment: ah sorry, i missed the fact you were using a library, i'll try that tomorrow

Comment: btw - there is an AppCompat Spinner - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.html

Comment: Thanks. I suspect the problem's likely due to the library then. I'll try out the regular Spinner.